# Error: no named parameter with the name 'color' Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

So I'm new to Dart & Flutter and have run across a problem. I'm trying to learn the layout and make subtle UI changes to text & button widgets. Here I'm trying to change the color of the `ElevatedButton` to `blue`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Text('Answer 1'),
        onPressed: null,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I run the code I get this error:

`Error: no named parameter with the name 'color'`

I thought with buttons there were color parameters that you could change. What would be the correct way of implementing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can style ElevatedButton by using the styleFrom

```
ElevatedButton(
      child: const Text('Button'),
      onPressed: () {},
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Colors.purple,
    ),
```

or you can use ButtonStyle class

```
ElevatedButton(
      child: const Text('Button'),
      onPressed: () {},
      style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom({
    Color primary, // set the background color 
    Color onPrimary,  // foreground
  }),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, Some widget deal with styles and themes for general app theme purposes, because of that it doesn't allow for changing the color directly, but with style parameters:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom({
    Color primary: Colors.green,
    Color onPrimary: Colors.white,  
  }),
),
```

For more information please visit [Flutter documents ElevatedButton.styeFrom](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton/styleFrom.html) and experiment with different parameters.

Welcome to Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can style ElevatedButton by :

```
ElevatedButton(
       style: ButtonStyle(
             backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty
             .all<Color>(Colors.blue),
             foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty
            .all<Color>(Colors.white),
        ),
      child: Text('your text'),
      onPressed: null,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your flutter SDK. That happened as SDK is not updated.

To update your flutter SKD, open CMD from windows and command "flutter upgrade".